# Oracle restore database to a "newer" version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-restore

**Is it possible to test the incremental backups ... well, incrementally?** If so: How? -and not using the words "duplicate" and "standby".

*Setup*

- Multi-TB Oracle 11g (11.2.0.2) database, about 70% of data is in a readonly tablespace.
- Backup: weekly level 0 copy (except readonly), semi-daily level 1 incremental (differential data+archivelog).

After the level 0 backup, we ship all backup files to a test rig (offline for all intents and purposes) and perform a full restore and recovery. What i want, is to move the incremental backup (< 50G) to the test rig and test only those bits. A recovery test could (in my head) complete in minutes, alternatively in a few hours if the readonly data could somehow be preserved. Otherwise it takes ~9 hours for a full restore+recovery.

The ultimate goal is to reduce the disaster recovery testing time by the ~70% taken by the readonly tablespace on the 12 hour incremental cycles - a full restore/recovery once a week is required by policy.

If my - as yet incomplete - solution is way off suggestions are most welcome (still not using "duplicate" or "standby" :o).

**EDIT Oct 4 2011:**
So i figured out how to avoid restoring the readonly tablespace on every test, so that's 70% time saved. What remains is to figure out whether it's possible to restore only the latest incremental backup onto the test-rig.

To be clear: Sunday I end up with at fresh restore+recover of everything, including readonly. Every 12 hours I perform a new restore-test, which skips the readonly bits but performs a level 0 restore of the remaining 30%, then applies the incrementals - in effect rolling back to Sunday and then catching up to the latest incremental.

What I'd like is to do a full restore sunday, and every 12 hours "apply" only the latest incremental backup to this restore and avoid the rollback to Sunday.

Comment: Ok, so to partially answer my own question..
It is possible to restore new controlfile (and spfile) on top of my test db, then have RMAN do a restore. In the process it asserts that the readonly tablespace images are "already restored to disk X" and proceeds to restore the level 0 backup images. So 70% saved so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this needs to answered, if only partially, so here you go:

The recovery-part is still open, but avoiding the readonly-tablespace bit is solved using transferable tablespaces. Basically,

- mark your readonly tablespace as transferable
- generate a dump file using expdp
- copy your datafiles to the test rig
- do a restore, but skip the tablespace in question
- drop tablespace from database
- impdp to your database. (essentially re-create from import)

We did this for a 3TB tablespace, took all of 30 seconds. (and 10 hours to copy :oP)

A word of caution: marking as transferable and dropping a tablespace may not be the right thing to do, especially if you have dependencies between tablespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the split between backup time, transfer time, and restore time for your configuration but here are my thoughts.

If you want to reduce **restore** time investigate the CHECK READONLY parameter for the RMAN RESTORE command. It sounds like you can keep a copy of your read-only datafiles on your target system and not have incur the overhead of RMAN pushing all those bits and bytes around at restore time.

You didn't mention version so from the 9i RMAN documentation for RMAN RESTORE command:

> CHECK READONLY
>   Checks the headers of read-only files to ensure that they are current before omitting them from the recovery.

If you want to reduce **transfer** time of your Level 0 backupset and can guarantee safety of the readonly data files, investigated the SKIP READONLY parameter for BACKUP command.

> SKIP READONLY
>   Specifies that read-only datafiles should be excluded from the backup set.

If you are paranoid (like me) and need another level of verification you could run a checksum your readonly datafile(s) on both sides to make sure you get back the same value.

But just be aware of how you are handling this situation - will the same procedure be followed in the event of a true restore scenario (whether it is CHECK READONLY or another method)?

Comment: Hi David. I already got the readonly part (as my comment above was supposed to indicate). I have updated the question a bit to reflect the remaining issue.

Comment: Do you open the database after each restore or do you just check that the restore went OK? If it is sitting there and you recover the incremental -- can't you just keep transferring and restoring backupsets as they are produced from the source system?

Comment: Yes, continuous transfer of backupsets as they're generated is the goal. And it seems silly, but yes we open the database after recovery.  But would it work if we don't? 

Actually I'm thinking .. our incrementals contain both block changes and archivelog, so we propably ruin everything when we recover the ~5 minutes worth of archivelog after the final incremenal.

Comment: Opening doesn't seem that silly - you want to know if the DB will open without complaining right? :) I see what you're getting at though, after applying archived logs it seems your datafiles would be halfway between the previous restore (a Level 1 or 0) and the new Level 1 you are trying to apply. Not sure if RMAN allows you to 'catch up' with that newly created Level 1. Have you tried it? I am curious what new exciting error messages you might get out of RMAN. I am wondering if it wouldn't first check SCN and not allow the operation.